# Best way to add classpath to build.xml

Tags: java, ant, classpath, build.xml

I have this `target` in build.xml to compile a class:

```
<target name="-do-compile" depends="init, deps-jar, -pre-pre-compile, -pre-compile, -copy-manifest, -copy-persistence-xml, -copy-webdir, library-inclusion-in-archive,library-inclusion-in-manifest" if="have.sources">
    <webproject2:javac destdir="${build.classes.dir.real}"/>
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir.real}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes}"/>
        </copy>
</target>
```

There is also this:

```
<target name="-init-macrodef-javac">
        <macrodef name="javac" uri="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/web-project/2">
            <attribute name="srcdir" default="${src.dir}"/>
            <attribute name="destdir" default="${build.classes.dir.real}"/>
            <attribute name="classpath" default="${javac.classpath}:${j2ee.platform.classpath}"/>
            <attribute name="debug" default="${javac.debug}"/>
            <element name="customize" optional="true"/>
            <sequential>
                <javac srcdir="@{srcdir}" destdir="@{destdir}" debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" source="${javac.source}" target="${javac.target}" includeantruntime="false">
                    <classpath>
                        <path path="@{classpath}"/>
                    </classpath>
                    <compilerarg line="${javac.compilerargs}"/>
                    <customize/>
                </javac>
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>
    </target>
```

During compilation, I got an error 'javax.servlet does not exist'. So I have to add `classpath` to servlet-api.jar, which is in `/opt/java/common/`. What is the best way to do it in my build.xml, what should be modified?

As the question may look silly, one may downvote instead of answering. But this certainly won't help, which is what they are here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below line to your classpath element

```
<pathelement location="/opt/java/common/servlet-api.jar"/>
```

i.e in your build xml file

```
<javac srcdir="@{srcdir}" destdir="@{destdir}" debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"   
                        source="${javac.source}" target="${javac.target}" includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath>
          <path path="@{classpath}"/>
          <pathelement location="/opt/java/common/servlet-api.jar"/>
      </classpath>
      <compilerarg line="${javac.compilerargs}"/>
      <customize/>
</javac>
```

Please see http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html Path-like Structures Section